# Shell using path pulled from cell in workbook using VBA

Tags: r, excel, vba, shell

My code runs a model in R directly from Excel.

I want to simplify installation so instead of:

```
path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe"" C:\Users\diego\OneDrive\Otros\Escritorio\ProgramacionSemanal\ProgramacionSemanal.R"
```

I want to retrieve Rscript.exe and ProgramacionSemanal.R path directly from cell values in the same workbook.

I tried to replicate what I had before using the cell values:

```vb
Sub RunRscript()

Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String

pathRscript = Sheets("Configuracion").Range("B17")
pathForecast = Sheets("Configuracion").Range("B11")

path = """""""" & pathRscript & """""" & " " & pathForecast & """"

errorCode = shell.Run(path, 0, waitTillComplete)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of "". Here's my solution:

```
path = """" & pathRscript & """" & " " & pathForecast & """"
```